# Could trees be engineered to produce rainfall-nucleators?

Tags: genetics, biochemistry, biotechnology, environment

Scientists are using genetic engineering to make trees produce more terpenes. Is it possible to genetically engineer trees to produce more hygroscopic volatile organic compounds? These trees could be used in drought areas to create more rain.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Don't forget to take the [tour](http://biology.stackexchange.com/tour). Could you add a source for your terpenes claim? It would also help to give examples of hygroscopic volative organic compounds, although it's not essential.

Comment: I can't recall any hygroscopic volatile compound. Hygroscopic molecules  carry-out electrostatic attraction (polar or ionic whatever) with each-other, so they are in most cases not volatile.

Comment: Your question is just too broad (also opinion based). Please add details and avoid asking open ended questions.

Comment: I think it is 2 question : 1. could we genetically engineer trees to produce any compound?  (that is a broad question) and 2. hygroscopic materials sometimes used to produce artificial rainfall, so is there any volatile (organic-volatile preferable) compound that is also hygroscopic? (which is a pure chemistry question).

Comment: probably this question is inspired from any such artificial rainfall article like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_seeding#Methodology